# problem in saving in excel using sql stored procedure with dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

stored procedure :

```
alter  PROCEDURE usp_dailyjobwisereport_dayshift            
as             
/*                
exec usp_dailyjobwisereport_dayshift          
*/                
SET NOCOUNT ON                

begin              

delete from machinejob_report;

 insert into  machinejob_report   
    select coalesce(cast(description_name as varchar(28)), 'Grand Total:') as descriptionname, 
    sum(case when vfrm.job_id = '1001' then DateDiff(mi, 0, total_time)  end) as  CRATE_SMALL ,       
    sum(case when vfrm.job_id = '1002' then DateDiff(mi, 0, total_time)  end) as  CRATE_MEDIUM ,                  
    sum(case when vfrm.job_id = '9999' then DateDiff(mi, 0, total_time)  end) as  NO_SCHEDULE
    from    ven_fullreportmaster vfrm
             INNER JOIN ven_descriptionmaster VDM ON VDM.description_id = vfrm.description_id
          -- inner join ven_machinemaster vm on  vm.machine_id = vfrm..machine_id
                        where  vfrm.entry_date = convert(varchar, getdate()-9, 105)  
                      and  vfrm.shift_id =1 
                      and vfrm.description_id in (1,3,5)
                      and vfrm.is_task_completed ='Y' 
          group by   description_name  with rollup

 if (1=2) 
 begin
 select system_type_id, user_type_id from sys.types
end

 DECLARE @dynsql NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SELECT @dynsql = 
  CASE WHEN j1001>0 THEN ',j1001' ELSE '' END +                    
  CASE WHEN j1002>0 THEN ',j1002' ELSE '' END +        
  CASE WHEN j9999>0 THEN ',j9999' ELSE '' END               
  FROM machinejob_report  
  WHERE  machinename = 'Grand Total:'  
  IF(LEN(@dynsql) > 0)     
 BEGIN  
   /*
     DECLARE @f NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SELECT @f = COALESCE(@dynsql + ', ', '') + field FROM  ven_machinejob_report_temp  
    SET @dynsql = 'SELECT machinename ' + @f + ' FROM machinejob_report' 
  */
 SET @dynsql = STUFF(@dynsql,1,1,'SELECT machinename, ') + ' FROM machinejob_report'     
 EXEC(@dynsql)    
 END 

end                  

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Output of the above procedure:

```
  machinename     j1001     j1002     j9999
   EC              270      NULL       200
   RUN             NULL      420       300
   Grand Total:    270       420       500
```

Another procedure for saving it in xls:

```
alter procedure usp_dailyjobwisereport_dayshift_excel   
(    
  @db_name varchar(100), @schm_name varchar(100), @table_name varchar(100),@file_name  varchar(100)    
 )    
 as    

 --Generate column names as a recordset    
 declare @columns varchar(8000), @sql varchar(8000), @data_file varchar(100)    

set @columns = '''machinename'' as machinename,''1001'' as job1001, ''1002'' as job1002 , ''9999'' as job9999'; 

    --Create a dummy file to have actual data    
   select @data_file=substring(@file_name,1,len(@file_name)-charindex('\',reverse(@file_name)))+'\data_file.csv'    

  --Generate column names in the passed EXCEL file    
  set @sql='bcp " select * from (select '+@columns+') as t" queryout   c:\test.csv  -c -t,  -T -S ' + @@servername    
  exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql   

    --Generate data in the dummy file    
    set @sql='bcp "exec Test..usp_dailyjobwisereport_dayshift " queryout   c:\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S ' + @@servername    
   exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql    

 --Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file    
   set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "'+@file_name+'"'''    
  exec(@sql)    

--Delete dummy file     
--set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''    
--exec(@sql)    

--EXEC usp_dailyjobwisereport_dayshift_excel Test','[dbo]', 'usp_dailyjobwisereport_dayshift','c:\test.csv'
```

When I execute the above procedure.. it's not showing any error.. but only one column is saved in the .csv /.xls file...

Output in the .csv file:

```
  EC
```

Please help me out to solve this issue...

### Solution:

i have created another dynamic table in the above procedure next to dynamic select statement  and inserted the result set into that table and

```
 set @f = STUFF(@dyncreate,1,6,'create table ven_machinejob_report_temp( descriptionname nvarchar(111),' )  + '   int )'
  exec(@f)
  insert into ven_machinejob_report_temp   
  EXEC(@dynsql)
```

again used that newly created table in the procedure for saving it in xls:

```
 --Generate data in the dummy file    
 set @sql='bcp " select * from Test..ven_machinejob_report_temp " queryout   c:\data_file.csv  -c -t,  -T -S ' + @@servername    
 exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

and now i am able to get all the rows in the excel sheet

Comment: Quite honestly: I wouldn't do this inside SQL Server - why don't you retrieve the data from your stored procedure into e.g. C# and then create the file from there?? Would be **much easier** than messing around with dynamic SQL and `xp_cmdshell` and messy stuff like that..... SQL Server just isn't really ideal for creating and manipulating files - a front-end language (C#, PHP, Java - whatever) is much better suited for such a task!

Comment: i need to send this csv file attached along with the mail in the morning automatically..and also the company doesnt want to create a front end for this.so only i am struggling with this sql stuffs..

Comment: actually they asked me to do 2 deisgn reports, both of them are alike.first report is working perfectly ,all the columns are needed and in the 2nd report i have to do some filterations to drop some columns. i am new to this sql server..bit struggling with this report generation :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to do this piece of work in SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). It's specifically designed to handle this kind of thing.

If you need to generate two files and then attach them to an automated email, you could create both files in SSIS, and wrap the whole piece in a SQL Agent job which runs the SSIS job and then sends the email.

Hope this makes sense to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx